# Rename image to random

Tags: image, random, file-rename

I'm working on an image uploader and if a user uploads a image I want to change the image name to something unique.

Imgur also does this for example "11Z6nlI.jpg"

So **how can I generate a unique combination**? I was thinking of using a timestamp since but that will also causes problems when more users upload at the same second.

I hope you guys can help me, I'm working in **PHP**

Answer (score 1):

Although sometimes clunky, GUIDs are a good way to generate unique strings.   See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) for a way to generate GUIDs within PHP.